# What does $\iff$ represent in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

After asking several people, I realized that this question might be deceptively simple and **require knowledge outside of Linear Algebra**.

In Linear Algebra, there is the following existing notation, which I find very convenient:

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & 3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\iff
\begin{cases}
2x + 2y = 4 \\
x + 3y = 6
\end{cases} \tag{0}
$

It is understood that the *augmented matrix* (of the *coefficient matrix* and the *vector of constants*) of a system of linear equations is **in some sense equivalent** to that system of linear equations.

This sort of equivalence can be demonstrated in the following example:

Let's say we have the same linear system in variables x,y which are, by implicit convention, members of the set of real numbers

$
\begin{cases}
2x + 2y = 4 \\
x + 3y = 6
\end{cases}
 \tag{1}$

There are the following three *mathematical objects* that are associated with Linear system (1) and relevant to the discourse:

$\begin{cases}
A \text{ is the } \textit{coefficient matrix} \text{ of Linear system (1)} & (2.a) \\
A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} & (2.b) \\
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 \\
1 & 3
\end{bmatrix} & (2.c)
\end{cases} \tag{2}$

$
\begin{cases}
\textbf{b} \text{ is the } \textit{vector of constants} \text{ of Linear system (1)} & (3.a) \\
\textbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1} & (3.b) \\
\textbf{b} =
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\
6
\end{bmatrix} & (3.c)
\end{cases} \tag{3}
$

$\begin{cases}
\textbf{x} \text{ is the } \textit{vector of unknowns} \text{ of Linear system (1)} & (4.a) \\
\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1} & (4.b) \\
\textbf{x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix} & (4.c)
\end{cases}
\tag{4}$

The triple $(A,\textbf{b},\textbf{x})$ allows to syntactically form the *matrix form* of Linear system (1):

$A \textbf{x} = \textbf{b} \tag{5}$

As pointed out by many practitioners, the exact names of variables are often not of great importance, whereas what important is in fact their *order*. **Perhaps** for that reason there exists *augmented matrix notation* described in ["Linear Algebra"](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Elinear/linear-guest.pdf) by Cherney, D.; Denton, T.; Thomas, R. & Waldron, A. This notation (or rather a family thereof) uses the same syntax that usually denotes matrices, for instance
$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & 3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$, to instead (unambiguously in context) denote the corresponding system of linear equations.

The syntax in (0) can be rendered/interpreted in *augmented matrix notation*, but the syntax below from the aforementioned ["Linear Algebra"](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Elinear/linear-guest.pdf) by Cherney et al cannot:

$
\left.\begin{array}{rrrrr}
    x & + & y & = & 2 \\
    2x & + & 2y & = & 5
  \end{array}\right\rbrace
\iff
\left(\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    2 & 2 & 5
  \end{array}\right)
\sim
\left(\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}\right)
\iff
\begin{cases}
x + y = 2 \\
0 + 0 = 1
\end{cases}
$

In Linear Algebra, $\sim$ denotes [Row equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_equivalence), the sort of *equivalence relations* between matrices whose *row spaces* are equal or, equivalently, if one matrix can be changed to the other through a sequence of *elementary row operations*.

From the notation, I can assume that the sort of equivalence demonstrated in (0) is *logical equivalence*; however, the important question is in which sort of logic these *mathematical objects* (matrix and a linear system) are "logically equivalent". For the category theorists the same question can be rephrased as "in which category these objects are isomorphic" and how can one possibly translate this interpretation in the language of Logic.

Comment: It becomes definitional.  We can define a bijective map from the set of all systems of linear equations on 2 variables to the set of $2\times 3$ matrices.  The augmented matrix is defined as the matrix representation of the system of linear equations.

Comment: @DougM According to the definition of definitional equality from HoTT
https://ncatlab.org/homotopytypetheory/show/definitional+equality and the definition of judgement https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/judgment, the definitional equality is "generic" over the metalanguage (a deductive system or a logical framework). You are correct in a sense that it is indeed a definitional equality. The logical framework (what I called logic) is not clear to me. That's why I explicitly asked these questions in the end.

Comment: In mathematics in general it means "if and only if" (iff).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It seems that you have totally skipped reading my question and answered the one that you thought I was asking. "If and only if" itself can be mean logical or material equivalence. In the question, I explicitly stated what was asked. I thank you for the mere attempt to help, but could you, please, read my question first and pay especially close attention to the end of it?

Comment: I confirm; it is iff that in "common" math jargon is logical equivalence. The formula is not a formula of symbolic logic; thus, the bi-conditional connective is out of place there. But you have to remember that in classical logic $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent iff $\vDash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I concur with the fact that the formula is not a formula of symbolic logic. However, I disagree with you regarding the bi-conditional connective being "out of place" there. There might be a logic (logical framework), of which I am not aware, that interprets matrices as relations. It might not have been formalized, yet; however logicians can give some clues on how to give at least its semi-formal description.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I had another round of thought and it seems that it could be a formula of symbolic logic. It just it has one interesting property that complicates its rules of inference. For natural languages, analogous concept is called polysemy, for programming languages, its analogue is called ad hoc polymorphism. The latter is more closely related, because it is possible for well-formed programs to be unambiguously translated for the compilation target.